# Set dynamic restConfiguration port without use of file based Property Placeholder

Tags: spring, apache-camel

Originally, I was using file based bridgePropertyPlaceholder to set restConfiguration port dynamically.

```
<bean id="bridgePropertyPlaceholder" class="org.apache.camel.spring.spi.BridgePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>file:./connection_${ENV}.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<restConfiguration component="restlet" host="localhost" port="{{rest.port}}"/>
```

The value of `${ENV}` come from environment variable and value of `{{rest.port}}` come from `connection_${ENV}.properties`

---

Now, I want to avoid using `connection_${ENV}.properties` to bypass new deployment system's limitation and move the value of `{{rest.port}}` to environment variable and I hit:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property with key [rest.port] not found in properties from text: {{rest.port}}
```

If I further change restConfiguration as below

```
<restConfiguration component="restlet" host="localhost" port="${rest.port}"/>
```

I hit Type Conversion problem:

```
Caused by: org.apache.camel.TypeConversionException: Error during type conversion from type: java.lang.String to the required type: java.lang.Integer with value ${rest.port} due java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${rest.port}"
```

---

My Question is: how to set dynamic restConfiguration port **without** use of file based Property Placeholder?

Remark: I know there exist workaround using java VM argument (i.e. -Drest.port=1234 ), but this method is not what I want.

Comment: When writing `port="${httprestnew.port}"` did you mean `port="${rest.port}"`? Also, what is the version of Camel which you are using here?

Comment: @Poger code updated to `port="${rest.port}"`. I change the term to make it more clear. The version I am using is 2.18.0.

Comment: In your properties file, is the value of rest.port enclosed in quotes?

Comment: @hk6279 When you tried `{{rest.port}}` you got an error saying that the property cannot be found. I understand you want to take it from environmental variables. In this case you should have `REST_PORT` environmental variable set when running the application. Are you sure it is set?

Comment: @FedeE. No, the value of rest.port is NOT enclosed in quotes in property file

Comment: @Poger Try `REST_PORT`, not work and return same error as using `rest.port`

Comment: M question is that when you run your command prompt (or terminal) and print the value of `REST_PORT` environment variable (`echo $REST_PORT` or `echo %REST_PORT%`) - you see an expected value? You can also test if some environment variables which should be defined, like `path` or `java.home`, can be injected into your application (with `{{path}}` or `{{java.home}}`). If they work then there is probably something wrong with the setting of `REST_PORT` environment variable.

Comment: @Poger calling `env` command, I can see both `rest.port` and `path` exist. Try using `COMPUTERNAME` found in env set and return `Property with key [COMPUTERNAME] not found in properties from text:`